# Measurability of derivative of Lebesgue integral function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа*  that if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue-summable function on its domain then the derivative $\Phi'$ of the integral function, defined for any $x\in[a,b]$ by$$\Phi(x)=\int_{[a,x]}f d\mu$$where the Lebesgue integral is intented to be calculated according to the "canonical" linear Lebesgue measure, is measurable.

I should specify that I cannot use the fact that $\Phi'(x)=f(x)$ because that equality is [proven by Kolmogorov-Fomin's by using](http://librarum.org/book/10022/167) the very fact that $\Phi'$ is measurable.
I thank anybody for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Phi(x)$ is an absolutely continuous function of $x$ on $[a,b]$ so it is Borel-measurable.

Comment: Thank you so much! Why is $\Phi'$ measurable too? I heartily thank you again!

Comment: Every absolutely continuous function on $[a,b]$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ so it has (measurable) derivative a.e. on $[a,b]$.

Comment: I've reached the point where Kolmogorov-Fomin's deals with absolute continuity and, after studying several preliminary lemmas, I've realised that the text does show this property without using the fact that $\Phi'(x)=f(x)$. Thank you so much again!!!

Comment: @DavideZena you are very welcome.